# No data if queries are sent between TRUNCATE and SELECT INTO. Using MySQL innoDB

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, locking, innodb, truncate

Using a MySQL DB, I am having trouble with a stored procedure and event timer that I created.
I made an empty table that gets populated with data from another via SELECT INTO.
Prior to populating, I TRUNCATE the current data. It's used to track only log entries that occur within 2 months from the current date.

This turns a 350k+ log table into about 750 which really speeds up reporting queries.

The problem is that if a client sends a query precisely between the TRUNCATE statement and the SELECT INTO statement (which has a high probability considering the EVENT is set to run every 1 minute), the query returns no rows...

I have looked into locking a read on the table while this PROCEDURE is ran, but locks are not allowed in STORED PROCEDURES.

Can anyone come up with a workaround that (preferably) doesn't require a remodel?
I really need to be pointed in the right direction here.

Thanks,
Max

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question a bit here, but wouldn't it be more efficient to query on the table your inserting from? Or querying on a view from that table?

Comment: Not quite efficient. The query is sent from a login, which means hitting a table with 350k+ records takes about 6 seconds too long. However, querying the table on the server side into a new table of a specific date range ends up being around 750 records. Much faster to query the smaller table. A View is run when it's queried, so it doesn't really speed up things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest an alternate approach instead of truncating the table, and then selecting into it...

You can instead select your new data set into a new table.  Next, using a single `RENAME` command, rename the new table to the existing table and the existing table to some backup name.

```
RENAME TABLE existing_table TO backup_table, new_table TO existing_table;
```

This is a single, atomic operation... so it wouldn't be possible for the client to read from the data after it is emptied but before it is re-populated.

Alternately, you could change your `TRUNCATE` to a `DELETE FROM`, and then wrap this in a transaction along with the `SELECT INTO`:

```
START TRANSACTION
    DELETE FROM YourTable;
    SELECT INTO YourTable...;
COMMIT
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting the change from `TRUNCATE` to a `DELETE FROM` because `TRUNCATE TABLE` is DDL not DML. It will close a current transaction and start a new one (Page 418 of MySQL 5.0 Certification Study Guide : http://www.amazon.com/MySQL-5-0-Certification-Study-Guide/dp/0672328127)

Comment: Thank you so much for the fix! Since the table is less than 1k records, the DELETE FROM won't be much of a performance difference from TRUNCATE TABLE. Two great ideas, I'll have to do both and see which is best. Thanks again Michael!